# easyprocess.EasyProcessCheckInstalledError: cmd=['Xvfb', '-help'] OSError=[Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, centos, xvfb, pyvirtualdisplay

I'm trying to setup a display but it's telling me `No such file or directory`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/envs/venv/proj/scripts/my_file.py", line 44, in click
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800,600))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", line 33, in __init__
    self._obj = self.display_class(
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", line 51, in display_class
    cls.check_installed()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/xvfb.py", line 38, in check_installed
    ubuntu_package=PACKAGE).check_installed()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/easyprocess/__init__.py", line 209, in check_installed
    raise EasyProcessCheckInstalledError(self)
easyprocess.EasyProcessCheckInstalledError: cmd=['Xvfb', '-help']
OSError=[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Program install error!
```

Comment: it was shell path problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74157376/8108684

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You likely need to install either the `xvfb` package, or possibly the `xvfbwrapper`:

First check and see if [xvfb](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xvfb) is installed:

```
Xvfb -help
```

If the command is *not found* then you can usually install the `xvfb` package with the following command (or whichever package manager you generally use):

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

[xvfbwrapper](https://github.com/cgoldberg/xvfbwrapper) is  Python wrapper for running a display inside X virtual framebuffer (Xvfb).

You can install it with:

```
pip install xvfbwrapper
```

The error you are getting seems to be a result of either the command or module not being found.

Comment: Hi, `pip install xvfbwrapper` does not seem to cut it on windows. Any ideas?

Comment: @rojas, windows doesn't run X11.

Comment: @BartekR. Just remove anything related to pyvirtualdisplay on Windows. You don't need it because of Windows graphics engine

Comment: Hi, I installed xvfb through Xquartz and I made sure it was correctly installed by `Xvfb - help`, but it still says it can't detect xvfb. Thanks

Comment: @li.SQ: How have you installed Xquartz? It uses its own window system, and in order to use xvfb with it I believe you would need to compile it from source using particular options which it would require.

Comment: @I'L'l Yes, I have installed Xquartz by installing the .pkg file. Can you explain "compile it from source"?

Comment: @li.SQ: Check the following link where it mentions `xorg-server`: https://www.xquartz.org/Developer-Info.html. If you can't figure it out then I would recommend posting a new question as your issue isn't really related to this question.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this error on a Mac and (finally) solved it by install Xquartz: https://www.xquartz.org/ (reboot after install!)