# Python 2.7 - Selenium headless testing with Xvfb not working

Tags: macos, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

Note I have already looked at the following sources:

[easyprocess.EasyProcessCheckInstalledError: cmd=['Xvfb', '-help'] OSError=[Errno 2] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173839/easyprocess-easyprocesscheckinstallederror-cmd-xvfb-help-oserror-errno#32173967)

[How do I run Selenium in Xvfb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb#6300672)

Which did not solve my problem.

I am using:

- Python 2.7
- selenium 3.0.2
- xvfbwrapper 0.2.9
- PyVirtualDisplay 0.2.1

Running on Mac OSX El Capitan (10.11.6 (15G1108))

I get the following error (which is the same one that is in the above link):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/test.py", line 50, in <module>
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", line 34, in __init__
    self._obj = self.display_class(
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/display.py", line 52, in display_class
    cls.check_installed()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyvirtualdisplay/xvfb.py", line 38, in check_installed
    ubuntu_package=PACKAGE).check_installed()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/easyprocess/__init__.py", line 180, in check_installed
    raise EasyProcessCheckInstalledError(self)
EasyProcessCheckInstalledError: cmd=['Xvfb', '-help']
OSError=[Errno 2] No such file or directory
Program install error!
```

I know I have Xvfb installed as well:

```
Xvfb -help
use: X [:<display>] [option]
-a #                   default pointer acceleration (factor)
-ac                    disable access control restrictions
-audit int             set audit trail level
-auth file             select authorization file
-br                    create root window with black background
+bs                    enable any backing store support
-bs                    disable any backing store support
-c                     turns off key-click
...
-pixdepths list-of-int support given pixmap depths
+/-render          turn on/off RENDER extension support(default on)
-linebias n            adjust thin line pixelization
-blackpixel n          pixel value for black
-whitepixel n          pixel value for white
-fbdir directory       put framebuffers in mmap'ed files in directory
-shmem                 put framebuffers in shared memory
```

If the pip install is looking for xvfb in a different directory, some guidance would be appreciated as to how to redirect where it's looking.

Here is my code:

```
from easyprocess import EasyProcess
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# now Firefox will run in a virtual display. 
# you will not see the browser.
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.title
browser.quit()

display.stop()
```

I've done countless pip installs and google searches and nothing has helped so far, the ultimate end goal is to have a headless automation that is capable of handling downloads, something PhantomJS is unable to do. Any help in that subject would be appreciated as well.

Comment: you can't use this on osx

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg What can I use? I defected to casperjs but if I want to use python how can I run it headless on OSX?

Comment: Chrome just released their headless version with version 59+. You can check this out.

Answer (score 2):

I dont see why you cant use this with osx, I have done that in past. But I have a better solution. Why dont you use [docker](https://www.docker.com/) + [VNC](https://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/) . install any browser of your choice and run everything in the background 
Advantage:
1. Everything runs in the background. 
2. Monitor execution in the browser with VNC web view
3. launch as many container as you want for parallel execution.