# Running Chrome headless in Python 2.7 with Selenium on Windows to download files

Tags: python, windows, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

tl;dr: I want to do what [Python 2.7 - Selenium headless testing with Xvfb not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205673/python-2-7-selenium-headless-testing-with-xvfb-not-working) <-- this person does, but on Windows.

Non-negotiable: Navigate a headless webdriver that allows for download of files.

From reading other answers, it looks like xvfb isn't available for Windows, so PyVirtualDisplay can't be used with Chrome: [easyprocess.EasyProcessCheckInstalledError: cmd=['Xvfb', '-help'] OSError=[Errno 2] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173839/easyprocess-easyprocesscheckinstallederror-cmd-xvfb-help-oserror-errno?noredirect=1&lq=1)

It also seems like it requires a lot of crazy hacks to get PhantomJS to download files.

Some answers suggest the use of urrlib or HTTPrequest:

[Basic http file downloading and saving to disk in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19602931/basic-http-file-downloading-and-saving-to-disk-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[How to download a file with Python, Selenium and PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615811/how-to-download-a-file-with-python-selenium-and-phantomjs?noredirect=1&lq=1)

...which would work, except to get to the files I want to download, I have to login and do a bunch of Xpath navigating, using Selenium.

Is there an easier way to do this? (in the hope that there's something new since the previous related posts)

Comment: Is building a forked PhantomJS with download support an option?

Comment: Yes! Is there an existing fork of PhantomJS that does that?